# How to render array parameter in pug file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I want to use a pug template file to render html.
Here is the pug file **temp1.pug**:

```
h1 hello!
p here is my friends:
  ul
    each val,index in !{friends}
      li='friend'+(index+1)+ ' ' + val
```

I want to render the pug file by using array in parameter friends:

```js
const templateRender = pug.compileFile('./temp1.pug');
console.log(templateRender({friends:['aaa','bbb']}));
```

It is supposed to have the output like:

```
<h1>hello!</h1>
<p>here is my friends:
<ul>
<li>friend 1: aaa</li>
<li>friend 2: bbb</li>
</ul>
</p>
```

but the actual output is:

```
<h1>hello!</h1>
<p>here is my friends:
<ul></ul>
</p>
```

It seemed that pug complier completely ignore my array input. Is there any idea to use array parameters to render this page?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
each val,index in friends
```

Comment: It works. Thank you